# Show basis for a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A Subbasis $\mathcal R$ of a set $X$ is defined to a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. Show that the collection $\mathcal B$ of all finite intersections of element of $\mathcal R$ is a topological basis of $X$.

Attempt :

> Let $X$ be a set, let $\mathcal B$ a collection of subsets of $X$, namely $\mathcal B = ${$B_\alpha$}$_{\alpha \in I}$. $\mathcal B$ is called a topological basis of $X$ if satisfy :
>
> 1. For any $x \in X$, there is an element $B_\alpha \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B_\alpha$.
> 2. For any $x \in X$, if there exists $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal B$ such that $x\in (B_1\cap B_2)$ then there is $B_3 \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in B_3 \subset (B_1 \cap B_2)$

How to show that collection $\mathcal B$ of all finite intersections of element of $\mathcal R$ satisfy the two conditions for a basis for a topology ?

Comment: chapter 2, section 13, there's everything you need. http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/munkres2.pdf

Comment: That link gives a 404

Answer (score 1):

$R$ satisfies $1$ because its union is $X$. The closure over finite intersections satisfies $2$ (choose $B_3$ equal to $B_1$ intersection $B_2$).

Comment: can you explain in more detail ? thank you

Comment: @user326307 Have you tried to comprehend my answer?

Comment: yes, but i am still confuse. I understand about topological space, but for topological basis it's still disconcerting

Comment: @user326307 Do you see that it satisfies 1? Do you see that it satisfies 2?

Comment: not yet, can you give an example the same as with my question ?

Comment: @user326307 The question is about understanding the definition. This answer in fact requires nothing more than an elementary understanding of sets and their intersections. If in doubt draw a (very simple) diagram to show the sets. It is far easier than you imagine and the ideas of topology and basis are probably getting in the way.

Comment: @user326307 Since R has X as its union then one of its elements contains any x in X. That is, each x has a neighborhood B in R. The closure over finite intersections satisfies 2 because B_1 intersect B_2 is a subset of B_1 intersect B_2 .